# Get text value from .txt file

Tags: javascript, html, variables, get

I have a script which gets a value from a .txt file, I have done it with a number value where it works perfectly, but when I want to do it with another .txt file, which is a text and not a number I get the "NaN" error which I know stands for "not a number", but then how do I change it to work so that I can get the value text in the .txt file?

My script.

```
    <div class="displayNameCurrent">
        Display name: <span id="displayNameDisplay"></span>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var read = new XMLHttpRequest();
        read.open('GET', 'displayNameFile.txt', false);
        read.send();

        var displayName = parseInt(read.responseText)
        document.getElementById("displayNameDisplay").innerHTML = displayName;
   </script>
```

Comment: You're using parseInt, which is intended to work with numbers, hence it giving "NaN". Try removing the parseInt before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to convert the text to an integer, simply don't run `parseInt` over it.